# Change the other nth children on click javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, this, siblings

**Original Question -**

Is there a way for me to set all of the other buttons in the table generated via ASP. Net Core using Razor Pages to a specific image (via Font-Awesome Icon, therefore it's a class that I'm changing) using Javascript. as the user clicks on one of the buttons (which will change, then reset the others).

**Update to show progress...**

I've managed to get the suggetion from @mjw to work, but it is behaving strangly. I'm implementing the `.siblings()` jquery approach as suggested and it seems to work. However, I think I'm referencing the wrong bits of part of the DOM.

It now works exactly as I want but it treats the two tables as seperate and isn't affecting the buttons that I think are "siblings()".

**Final Update to show solution...**

I took @mjw's advice again and changed my id's to classes and referenced the edited the javascript function so it is being triggered by the class

From `$('#appendRqmts:nth-child(n)').on('click', function () {`

To `$('.appendRqmts:nth-child(n)').on('click', function () {`

And the html...

From

`<td class="border-0 btn-link py-1" data-id="209" id="appendRqmts">
<i class="fas fa-clipboard-list" id="appendRqmts_icon" /></td>`

To

`<td class="border-0 btn-link py-1 appendRqmts" data-id="209">
<i class="fas fa-clipboard-list appendRqmts_icon"></i></td>`

Here is the updated snippet:

```js
//-------------Specific Roles ***Qualifications*** Table Builder-------------//

$(function() {
$('.appendRqmts:nth-child(n)').on('click', function() {

var current_icon = $(this).find('i');
var sibling_icons = $(this).parentsUntil('div').siblings().find(".appendRqmts_icon");

current_icon.removeClass('fas fa-clipboard-list').addClass('fas fa-sign-in-alt');
sibling_icons.removeClass('fas fa-sign-in-alt').addClass('fas fa-clipboard-list');

//Code for appending data to page is omitted

});
});

//Here is the code that I used to control the clear all button. Added after figuring out how to do it.
$('#clearSpecRoleRqmts').on('click', function() {
  
  var sibling_icons = $(this).parents('.card-body').find('.specRole_Table').find('.appendRqmts_icon');

  sibling_icons.removeClass('fas fa-sign-in-alt').addClass('fas fa-clipboard-list');

});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/507e05d76d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="card border-0">
    <div class="card-header pb-0 bg-transparent border-0">
      <div class="row animate__animated animate__fadeInDown animate__delay-1s">
        <div class="col-1 pb-0 pl-1">
          <h3 class="pl-0"><i class="fas fa-users"></i></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-11 pb-0">
          <h3 class="px-2 py-0 animate__animated animate__fadeInDown animate__delay-1s">
            <span data-toggle="titleTooltip" title="<p>Some specific roles have additional requirements to the ones listed on the right of the screen.</p><p>Click on the link to open the list of additional requirements.</p>">Specific Roles</span>
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body pl-0 pt-0">
      <div class="row animate__animated animate__fadeInUp animate__delay-3s pt-1 pb-3">
        <div class="col-10">
          <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block" id="clearSpecRoleRqmts">
            <i class="fas fa-eraser"></i> Clear Specific Role Requirements
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <table class="table lists-table py-0 border-0 specRole_Table">
        <tr class="py-0">
          <td class="border-0 py-1 animate__animated animate__fadeInUp animate__delay-2s specRole_JobCat">
            Working in <b>Nursing</b>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="border-0 pb-1 pt-2 animate__animated animate__fadeInUp animate__delay-2s col-10 specRole_SpecRoleType">
            <h6>6 <span> | </span> Senior Registered Nurse | Adult</h6>
          </td>
          <td class="py-1 border-0 appendRqmts_td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border-0 py-1 animate__animated animate__fadeInUp animate__delay-2s col-10 specRole_SpecRoleType">
            Discharge
          </td>
          <td class="py-1 border-0 appendRqmts_td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border-0 py-1 animate__animated animate__fadeInUp animate__delay-2s col-10 specRole_SpecRoleType">
            EPMA
            <span> (</span>Specialist<span>)</span>
          </td>
          <td class="border-0 animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft animate__delay-2s btn-link py-1 text-center col-2 appendRqmts" data-id="116">
            <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list appendRqmts_icon"></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border-0 py-1 animate__animated animate__fadeInUp animate__delay-2s col-10 specRole_SpecRoleType">
            Orthopadic
            <span> (</span>Specialist<span>)</span>
          </td>
          <td class="py-1 border-0 appendRqmts_td"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border-0 py-1 animate__animated animate__fadeInUp animate__delay-2s col-10 specRole_SpecRoleType">
            Research
            <span> (</span>Specialist<span>)</span>
          </td>
          <td class="border-0 animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft animate__delay-2s btn-link py-1 text-center col-2 appendRqmts" data-id="119">
            <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list appendRqmts_icon"></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border-0 py-1 animate__animated animate__fadeInUp animate__delay-2s col-10 specRole_SpecRoleType">
            IPC &amp; TV
            <span> (</span>Specialist<span>)</span>
          </td>
          <td class="border-0 animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft animate__delay-2s btn-link py-1 text-center col-2 appendRqmts" data-id="120">
            <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list appendRqmts_icon"></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border-0 pb-1 pt-2 animate__animated animate__fadeInUp animate__delay-2s col-10 specRole_SpecRoleType">
            <h6>6 <span> | </span> Senior Registered Nurse | Children&#x27;s</h6>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border-0 py-1 animate__animated animate__fadeInUp animate__delay-2s col-10 specRole_SpecRoleType">
            Outpatients
            <span> (</span>Specialist<span>)</span>
          </td>
          <td class="border-0 animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft animate__delay-2s btn-link py-1 text-center col-2 appendRqmts" data-id="116">
            <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list appendRqmts_icon"></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border-0 pb-1 pt-2 animate__animated animate__fadeInUp animate__delay-2s col-10 specRole_SpecRoleType">
            <h6>6 <span> | </span> Senior Registered Nurse | Theatre</h6>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border-0 py-1 animate__animated animate__fadeInUp animate__delay-2s col-10 specRole_SpecRoleType">
            Practitioner
          </td>
          <td class="border-0 animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft animate__delay-2s btn-link py-1 text-center col-2 appendRqmts" data-id="116">
            <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list appendRqmts_icon"></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

As an extra side not to anyone struggling to figure out how to reference the correct part of the DOM (relative to the current object i.e. - `$(this)` ). I found it really helpful to just change the `bg-colour` class (when using bootstrap) until I knew I was affecting the correct DOM elements. For example:

```
var variable = $(this).parent().siblings().find('.domElementClass')

variable.addClass('bg-success')
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I would start by posting the rendered HTML output of the list/table you're wanting to add js to change the images. So you have a list and each item has a button. When clicking an item's button, you want to change that button to something else and every other item's button to something else as well? So clicked button will be different than the rest? For this, check out `.siblings()`

Comment: Hi @mjw, apologies for posting the ASP and not the rendered html. That would have made more sense. I’ll have a look at the .siblings() function and if it works I’ll post my solution. Thanks for the ‘point in the right direction’. Much appreciated.

Comment: No worries, just a suggestion when working with js/jQuery since it operates on the DOM. In my answer, i'm using the css method to assign a background color on each item, but you can easily modify this to add or remove a class, since I believe you mentioned you're using fontawesome glyphs for the button images? So you'd want `.addClass("fa-icon-name-1")` and `.removeClass("fa-icon-name-2")`

Comment: Hey @mjw, would you mind having a look at at this? I can’t get it to work consistently.

Comment: looks like the inconsistency you're seeing may be related to your ID structure. You have more than one element with an ID of `appendRqmts` and this is invalid HTML. You don't want to start from that when working with query selectors as it will inevitably cause weirdness. Not saying this is definitely your issue, but I would start by making these unique. If you need to select / bind the click action to all of those items, move the ID to a class and select them by class. Good luck

Comment: Hi @mjw, I changed the ids to classes ad it worked perfectly. Thanks. I'll update the code  when I get chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example demonstrating `.siblings()`. You want to find up the js function to the button click, and from there you have access to `this` item for changing the clicked item's image...and then the `siblings()` for setting the other images. Good luck

```js
// handle click and add class
$("button").on("click", function(){
  $(this).parent().css("background-color","blue");
  $(this).parent().siblings().css("background-color","green");
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <span class="item">First row &nbsp;<button>Change color</button></span>
  <span class="item">Second row &nbsp;<button>Change color</button></span>
  <span class="item">Third row &nbsp;<button>Change color</button></span>
  <span class="item">Fourth row &nbsp;<button>Change color</button></span>
</div>
```